# Seg fault on merge sort on strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting, mergesort

Been debugging this code for a while now and the problem I can't seem to find (probably just missing something stupid) is that my merge sort function (which works on an array of ints) isn't working on an array of strings.

```
void MergeSort(string *input, int lowBound, int highBound)
{
    int midBound;
    if (lowBound < highBound)
    {
        midBound = (lowBound + highBound) / 2;

        MergeSort(input, lowBound, midBound);
        MergeSort(input, midBound + 1, highBound);

        MergeArrs(input, lowBound, highBound, midBound);
    }
}

void MergeArrs(string *a, int lowBound, int highBound, int midBound)
{
    int i, j, idx; 
    string tmp[highBound - lowBound + 1];
    i = lowBound; //Index for front arr
    idx = 0;
    j = midBound + 1; //Index for back arr

    while (i <= midBound && j <= highBound)
    {
        if (a[i] < a[j])
        {
            tmp[idx] = a[i];
            idx++;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp[idx] = a[j];
            idx++;
            j++;
        }
    }

    while (i <= midBound)
    {
        tmp[idx] = a[i];
        idx++;
        i++;
    }

    while (j <= highBound)
    {
        tmp[idx] = a[j];
        idx++;
        j++;
    }

    for (i = lowBound; i <= highBound; i++)
    {
        a[i] = tmp[i - lowBound];
    }
}
```

If anyone has any idea where the seg fault is coming from, any info would be appreciated. My test array looks like this:

```
string arr[6] = {"alpha", "beta", "omega", "zeta", "epsilon", "beach"};
```

And is called like this:

```
MergeSort(arr, 0, 6);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `highBound` be the top *index* instead of the size?

Comment: I suspect an access out of bounds since it kind of worked with `int`s and stopped working with real objects which need to be properly initialized. Please test all your array accesses, i.e. `someArray[i]`, whether their indices are inside the expected range.

Comment: Among many other problems, `string tmp[highBound - lowBound + 1];` is not  valid C++.

Comment: @NeilButterworth that is not necessarily a problem. OP might be using an extension, it is not a problem on itself.

Comment: @Sergey It is a problem if it causes a stack overflow, which may very well result in a seg fault, which is what the OP is seeing. And using language extensions is always a bad idea.

Comment: Did you try a debugger? It can help you find the segfault yourself and it's a really useful tool in general.

Comment: @NeilButterworth `using language extensions is always a bad idea` - this is your personal opinion. You are entitled to it. As for stack overflow, something tells me OP is not causing stack overflow with an array of 6 elements.

Comment: Definitely not worried about a totally watertight program, the input won't be more than 100 MAX. GDB isn't giving me any useful information IMO, but I can link the output if that would be useful?

Comment: All the indices are within the expected range of 0-5 so that doesn't seem to be the problem. @phlipsy

Comment: Replace the array with a `std::array` or `std::vector` and use `arr.at(i)` instead of `a[i]` and see what happens.

Comment: I take it back @phlipsy! I think I've narrowed it down and I think highBound should be the top index, like the top comment mentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a smart man. By indexing, over 0 to 5 in my merge sort call the program works, because, duh, those are the highest and lowest indices.

It wouldn't segfault with ints because it was an array of primitives as @phlipsy said.